# TypeError: Cannot read property 'regenerate' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I'm new to node.js and trying to use 'express-session' to create and storage a session, the title is the bug, and below is my code. I check the origin code on github, but didn't find any question. pls help, thank you so much.

```
User.prototype.login = function (req, res, next) {

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        // 获取前台页面传过来的参数
        var user_name = req.param("user_name"),
            password = req.param('password');

        // 建立连接，向表中插入值
        var select = mysql.format(user_command.login, user_name);
        connection.query(select, function(err, result) {
            if(result) {
                if(result[0].password === password){
                    req.session.regenerate(function() {
                        if(err){
                            res.json({ret_code: 2, ret_message:'登陆失败' });
                        }
                        res.sessionID = user_name;
                        res.json({ret_code: 0, ret_msg: '登录成功'});
                    });
                }else {
                    res.redirect('/login');
                }
            }
            // 释放连接
            connection.release();
        });

    });
```

};

Comment: There is no function `req.session.regenerate`. You are trying to call it. Error.

Comment: thanks man, but the function is in the doc of "express-session", that's why I don't really understand.     you can search the function in the link: https://github.com/talentAN/session

Comment: Do you have somewhere in your code `app.use(session(`?

Comment: yes,  it's in my main.js, not in this page.  I just require 'express-session' module in this js file

Comment: What does `console.log(req.session)` write?

Comment: it write undefined

Comment: really confused.  @nicovank, if you have some time for me, the project is here git@github.com:talentAN/niceandeasy.git. anyway, thank you very much~ happy weekends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express middleware are executed in the order that you define them. Your problem is that you have set `app.use('./', routes)` before `app.use(session(...))`.

To fix this, just move the first line after the second.

```
app.use(session({
    // ...
});

app.use('./', routes);
```